# How to sort an NSArray where 1 value is dec and 1 value is float

Tags: objective-c, sorting

My current project does a great deal of aggregation and one of the values I wanted to sort on is coming back in 2 flavors

1. My first source will return 0.9 / 1 / 1.1
2. My second source will return 2.349823432 / 4.93432343

My question is 2 fold

- What type should I set on my object
  to capture this value so sorting
  works correctly.  I'm asking because
  I currently parse json and set these
  values manually.
- After the value is
  set what is the best way to sort w/
  the information provided?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to create a class to describe the values you are parsing, and define the sorting logic in that class.  A simple example,

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    NSNumber *someNum;
        NSString *someString;
...
}

@implementation MyClass

- (NSComparisonResult)compareNums:(MyClass *)myClassObject {
    return [self.someNum compare:myClassObject.someNum];
}
- (NSComparisonResult)compareStringsDescending:(MyClass *)myClassObject {
    return -1 * [self.someString compare:myClassObject.someString];
}
```

...

Now you can sort many myClass objects by doing this in some viewcontroller:

```
NSArray *mySortedArray = [self.myOriginalArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compareNums:)];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: someNum is a full property in this example right? I only ask because you ref by the self keyword

Answer (score 0):

```
sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Assuming that you have `NSNumber`'s in the array and not something like `NSValue` or so